# Show popup menu of files which call a specific function vim

Tags: popup-menu

In normal mode, I'll hover over a function declaration and I want to open a file which calls this function.

How can I open up the popup menu in normal mode and have it just open the file I select rather than using the popup menu for autocomplete?

Comment: `:help tags-and-searches`

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify your goals? It sounds like you want a popup-menu of files, each of which contains a call to your function, and you want to pick one to open?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yes this is correct.

Comment: @libby please [edit] your question to provide additional information - comments can get lost.